# How do I use cv.goodFeaturesToTrack from opencv.js?

Tags: opencv

The code I'm trying:

```
let src = cv.imread('inputImage');  // read from <img id="inputImage" />
let temp = new cv.Mat();
src.convertTo(temp, cv.CV_32FC1);  // cv.CV_32FC1 === 5

let features = new cv.Mat();
cv.goodFeaturesToTrack(temp, features, 500, 0.01, 10); // These numbers are arbitrary.
```

Me on the Browser Console:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (src.type() == (((0) & ((1 << 3) - 1)) + (((1)-1) << 3)) || src.type() == (((5) & ((1 << 3) - 1)) + (((1)-1) << 3))) in cornerEigenValsVecs, file /build/master-contrib_docs-lin64/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/corner.cpp, line 269 opencv.js:21:3644

Uncaught 6384400 - Exception catching is disabled, this exception cannot be caught. Compile with -s DISABLE_EXCEPTION_CATCHING=0 or DISABLE_EXCEPTION_CATCHING=2 to catch. opencv.js:21:1597503
(((0) & ((1 << 3) - 1)) + (((1)-1) << 3))
-> 0
cv.CV_8U
-> 0
(((5) & ((1 << 3) - 1)) + (((1)-1) << 3))
-> 5
cv.CV_32F
-> 5
cv.CV_32FC1
-> 5
cv.CV_8UC1
-> 0
```

Do I convert to another channel when using convertTo() or maybe use cv.cvtColor() instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input to `goodFeaturesToTrack` [should be an 8-bit or 32-bit single channel image](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/d1a/group__imgproc__feature.html#ga1d6bb77486c8f92d79c8793ad995d541). It seems you are actually passing a 3-channel image; the issue is that `convertTo` can be used to change bit-depth, but not the number of channels -- [see documentation here](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#adf88c60c5b4980e05bb556080916978b).

I would suggest doing this:

```
cv.cvtColor(src, src, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY); // convert to 1-channel
let features = new cv.Mat();
cv.goodFeaturesToTrack(src, features, 500, 0.01, 10);
```

In other words, `convertTo` call can be completely omitted.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to access the actual point data using features.data32F afterwards.